# Форма отправки e-mail через намерение

Tags: android

В приложение встроена форма обратной связи.
Есть форма для заполнения, которая через намерение вызывает почтовую программу, в которой поля адреса, темы и самого сообщения подгружаются из этой формы.
Как сделать так, чтобы адрес электронной почты в поле нельзя было изменить, но он был заполненным (у меня там только текст с атрибутом hint)?
Ну или вообще убрать эту строку из формы, но чтобы она была заполнена в письме

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SimpleEMail extends Activity {
    Button send;
    EditText address, subject, emailtext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simple_email);

        // Наши поля и кнопка
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.emailsendbutton);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailaddress);
        subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailsubject);
        emailtext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                // Кому
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { address.getText().toString() });
                // Зачем
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        subject.getText().toString());
                // О чём
                emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                        emailtext.getText().toString());

                emailIntent.setType("text/video");
                // Поехали!
                SimpleEMail.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,
                        "Отправка письма..."));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

лайаот

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailaddress"
        android:hint="email@email.ru"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailsubject"
        android:hint="Введите тему обращения"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/emailtext"
        android:hint="Введите сообщение разработчику"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/emailsendbutton"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:background="@drawable/style"
        android:text="Отправить" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убираем у EditText возможность ввода:

```
<Edittext
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   android:cursorVisible="false"
   android:focusable="false" 
   android:inputType="none" />
```

Или можно полностью убрать EditText.
А в коде

```
 // Кому
 emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[] { "myEmail@mail.ru" });
```